# Date.from(ZonedDateTime to instant) returning previous day

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

My variable in java of type `ZonedDateTime` is say `time="2017-01-03T00:00Z[UTZ]"` . And when i try to get Date from like this - `Date.from(time.toInstance())` it returns previous day i.e `Mon Jan 02 19:00:00 EST 2017`, I dont know why ? Could anyone shed some light on my it returns previous day ?

Comment: Compare the two time zones. Midnight UTC is 7PM EST the day prior.

Comment: What is your system timezone?

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

**Never use `java.util.Date` class.** That terrible class, along with `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat` and others are now legacy. The new `to`/`from` conversion methods added to the old classes are intended only for use when you are interoperating with old code not yet updated to *java.time*. Avoid `Date` whenever possible.

Among the many flaws in `Date` is its unfortunate behavior of dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text in its `toString` method. So it appears a `Date` has a time zone while actually a `Date` represents a moment in UTC. **In other words, [`Date::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#toString()) lies.** One of many reasons to avoid this class.

➥ In the winter of 2017, many of the time zones on the east coast of North America are five hours behind UTC. So midnight in UTC *is* simultaneously 7 PM (19:00) in New York, Montréal, etc. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

## *java.time*

The `Date` class was supplanted by `Instant` years ago.

> ZonedDateTime is say time="2017-01-03T00:00Z[UTZ]"

If you are trying to track moments in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), use either:

- [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html)
  `Instant.now()`
- [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object set to UTC.
  `OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC )`

Use the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class when you have a moment in the context of a time zone. A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) used by the people of a particular region.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
)
```

You can adjust between UTC and a zone. Same moment, different ways to view it, different wall-clock times.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

ZonedDateTime.toInstant() adjusts a moment from a time zone to UTC. You end up with the same moment, different wall-clock time, and possibly a different date for the same simultaneous point on the timeline. What you are seeing is not a problem, not a discrepancy.

Classes like LocalDate and ZonedDateTime provide a human view on time.
However, often we need to work with time viewed from a machine perspective. 
For this, we can use the Instant class which represents timestamps.

An Instant counts the time beginning from the first second of January 1, 1970 (1970-01-01 00:00:00) also called the EPOCH.

Instant values can be negative if they occurred before the epoch. They followISO 8601 the standard for representing date and time.

Also, use the Java Time API libraries introduced in Java 8 as there were many issues in the existing Date and Calendar APIs  Please 
 refer: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro